# Solve a nonlinear system of equation via sympy

Tags: sympy

I have a system of ODE and want to find equilibrium points by using nonlinsolve() but when i run it by jubyter or spyder the program keep running without any result.

```
N,x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,r1,r2,r3,r4,eta1,eta2,eta3,eta4,R,c1,c2,c3,c4,a11,a12,a21,a22,a31,a32,a41,a42,b12,h,h11,h12,h21,h22,h31,h32,h41,h42,s1,s2,s3,s4,epsilon1,epsilon2,omega1,omega2,K11,K22,beta11,beta21,beta31,beta41,beta12,beta22,beta32,beta42,gamma12=sp.symbols('x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2,r1,r2,r3,r4,eta1,eta2,eta3,eta4,N,R,c1,c2,c3,c4,a11,a12,a21,a22,a31,a32,a41,a42,b12,h,h11,h12,h21,h22,h31,h32,h41,h42,s1,s2,s3,s4,epsilon1,epsilon2,omega1,omega2,K11,K22,beta11,beta21,beta3a,beta41,beta12,beta22,beta32,beta42,gamma12')


F2=x1*(r1*(1-(eta1*x1+eta2*x2+eta3*x3+eta4*x4)/N)-(a11*y1)/(y1+a11*h11*x1)-(a12*y2)/(y2+a12*h12*x1))+s1

F3=x2*(r2*(1-(eta1*x1+eta2*x2+eta3*x3+eta4*x4)/N)-(a21*y1)/(y1+a21*h21*x2)-(a22*y2)/(y2+a22*h22*x2))+s2

F4=x3*(r3*(1-(eta1*x1+eta2*x2+eta3*x3+eta4*x4)/N)-(a31*y1)/(y1+a31*h31*x3)-(a32*y2)/(y2+a32*h32*x3))+s3

F5=x4*(r4*(1-(eta1*x1+eta2*x2+eta3*x3+eta4*x4)/N)-(a41*y1)/(y1+a42*h41*x4)-(a42*y2)/(y2+a42*h42*x4))+s4

F6=y1*(-epsilon1*(1+(y1+omega2*y2)/K11)-(b12*y2)/(y2+b12*h*y1)\
              +beta11*(a11*x1)/(y1+a11*h11*x1)\
              +beta21*(a21*x2)/(y1+a21*h21*x2)\
              +beta31*(a31*x3)/(y1+a31*h31*x3)\
              +beta41*(a41*x4)/(y1+a41*h41*x4))

F7=y2*(-epsilon2*(1+(omega1*y1+y2)/K22)+gamma12*(b12*y1)/(y2+b12*h*y1)\
              +beta12*(a12*x1)/(y2+a12*h12*x1)\
              +beta22*(a22*x2)/(y2+a22*h22*x2)\
              +beta32*(a32*x3)/(y2+a32*h32*x3)\
              +beta42*(a42*x4)/(y2+a42*h42*x4))   
equ=(F2,F3,F4,F5,F6,F7)
sol=nonlinsolve(equ,x1,x2,x3,x4,y1,y2)   
print(sol)
```

Is it possible to get the solution in terms of parameters?

Comment: You haven't included the call to nonlinsolve. It isn't clear to me what the uknowns are in this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your system of equations can be recast as multivariate polynomial system if you multiply through by all of the denominators. Doing this for example in the case of `F2` you would get

```
In [26]: F2.as_numer_denom()[0]                                                                                                   
Out[26]: 
s₁⋅x₁⋅(a₁₁⋅h₁₁⋅x₂ + y₂)⋅(a₁₂⋅h₁₂⋅x₂ + r₁) + x₂⋅(-a₁₁⋅x₁⋅y₂⋅(a₁₂⋅h₁₂⋅x₂ + r₁) - a₁₂⋅r₁⋅x₁⋅(a₁₁⋅h₁₁⋅x₂ + y₂) + r₂⋅(a₁₁⋅h₁₁⋅x₂ + y₂
)⋅(a₁₂⋅h₁₂⋅x₂ + r₁)⋅(-N⋅y₁ - η₂⋅x₂ - η₃⋅x₃ - η₄⋅x₄ + x₁))
```

We can see from here that the polynomial is of order 5 since it has terms like `x2**3*N*y1` so broadly you have a system of 7 polynomials not of low order. I expect that a general closed form solution will not be possible unless you are lucky.

Comment: The point is that I think that is what nonlinsolve will do when trying to solve this. To understand whether analytic solutions might exist you need to understand what kind of system of equations you have. You can get expressions for some unknowns in terms of others but that is not the same as getting a full solution for N and x1 that is free of unkowns.